# How to pass in custom parameters to the SKView delegate method view(nodeFor)

Tags: ios, arkit

I have an ARKit Spritekit project where I want to show different images for each ARAnchor.

I'm a bit confused on the best way to match the SKSpriteNode image I'm adding to each ARAnchor becuase there is some inversion of control between the `SKScene` Scene class and the view controller.

I'm adding the anchors in Scene.swift, and in the view controller, I handle the delegate method.

```
func view(_ view: ARSKView, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SKNode? {
    // Create and configure a node for the anchor added to the view's session.
    // this image url needs to be dynamic and vary for each node
    let imageURL = "https://farm1.staticflickr.com/[SOMEID].jpg"
    let url = URL(string: imageURL)
    let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!) 
    let theImage = UIImage(data: data!)
    let Texture = SKTexture(image: theImage!)
    return SKSpriteNode(texture: Texture)

}
```

My question is this: how should I pass in the dynamic image info?

1. I could subclass `ARAnchor` and set the imageUrl in the custom anchor class when I add the anchor to the `ARSKView` in Scene.swift
2. Should I insert the `ARAnchor` not from Scene.swift and instead from the view controller - and then somehow keep a link to that `ARAnchor` and to the SKSpriteNode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many possible ways to do this, so it all comes down to how you prefer to architect your app/game. Regarding the possibilities you asked about and their feasibility, though:

1. Yes, if you're creating your own `ARAnchor` objects and adding them to the `ARSession`, you can define an `ARAnchor` subclass (that includes properties like an image URL) and pass those instead. Your custom class will retain its identity and contents when it "comes out the other end"; you'll just need to check for it in your delegate method:

   ```
   func view(_ view: ARSKView, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SKNode? {
       if let anchor = anchor as? MyAnchor {
           let texture = self.textureForURL(anchor.imageURL)
           return SKSpriteNode(texture: texture)
       }
   }
   ```

   (Note `textureForURL` here is a placeholder for whatever code you use to load `SKTexture` objects from URLs.)
2. If you put your anchor management code in the view controller rather than the SpriteKit scene, the view can keep track of correspondences between nodes and anchors for you: see the `node(for:)` and `anchor(for:)` methods on `ARSKView`. (IMHO, `SKScene` is best thought of as a "data" class, so it's not a great place for subclassing to add logic.)

Comment: so even if I move the logic to the view controller - I would still probably want to to subclass ARAnchor like #1?

Comment: @MonkeyBonkey I wouldn't recommend to add attributes into ARAnchor subclass, because of it causes freezes for me.

Comment: I have one property in an ARAnchor subclass. For me the property is correct through `view(_:nodeFor:)`, but loses the property value subsequently.